# Calling c# custom actions from PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to execute a custom action method from power-shell here is the code I have written in c#

```
namespace MyCustomAction
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
       [CustomAction]
        public static Session TestResult(Session session)
        {
            session["name"] = "hello";
            return session;
        }
    }
}
```

After building t he solution here is how I am loading the assemblies

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll")

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("D:\CustomAction\\bin\x86\Debug\MyCustomAction.dll") | Out-Null
```

But I am not getting how to pass session to the method as required I tried the following but no luck

```
$session = [Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session]
[MyCustomAction.CustomActions]::TestResult($session)
```

Comment: Have you read this? Seems to be the same, though i've never tried this!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958493/execute-c-sharp-code-using-powershell

Comment: Why voted down?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a new object of your class, you can use the `New-Object`

```
$session = New-Object [Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session]
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object

Comment: Getting following error `New-Object : Cannot find type [[Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session]]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded`

Comment: Sorry, you don't need to give the square bracket "[" for your type `$session = New-Object Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session`

Comment: Then I am getting following error `New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session.`